# Need data structure to support a matrix operation

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I need a specific data structure and I am not sure what should I use.

I have a matrix NxN. Each cell has some integer value. For any rectangle in the matrix I need to calculate a "price" such that:

```
price = sum( #value_of_field * #distance_from_target ) over cells in rectangle
```

Distance is manhattan distance and target can be any cell in the rectangle. Matrix is fixed (unchanging).

Example:

```
1 2
1 2
```

left top is [0;0], left bottom is [0;1], right top is [1;0] and right bottom is [1;1]

For example, given [0;0] in rectangle [0;0] - [1;1] (entire matrix) the price would be:

```
price = 1 * 0        +      2 * 1       +    1 * 1         +        2 * 2    =  7
        price of           price of           
        [0;0] *            [1;0] *           .....                   ....
        distance           distance
        from [0;0]         from [0;0]
```

How should I tackle this problem? Solution in m x n (where m, n are dimension of rectangle) would be easy, but it's to slow. How can speed this up (eg. precalculate something)?

Comment: What's your problem?  You're asking what data structure, but you've already said it's a matrix. A two dimensional array.

Comment: Define distance.  Are you using Manhattan distances?  Also, is the matrix fixed (unchanging) and the target always 0,0 ?  That is, for each problem instance, are you given a target and the bounds of a rectangle, or are you given a target, a rectangle, and a matrix?  Please edit question to answer these issues.

Comment: @kirelagin is manhattan distance between cell and the target.

Comment: @SteveWaddicor yes, but that's too slow (O(mn) for any rectangle, I need something faster == I guess precalculate something

Comment: @jwpat7 thanks for your input, I edited the questin. basically you are given matrix and then rectangle in it. Target can be any cell in the rectangle, not just [0;0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate Ai and Bi in advance:

- Ai = sum of elements on i-th row
- Bi = sum of elements on i-th column

[image: formula]

This will give you the answer.

The time complexity is `O(N)` for each price calculation. The time complexity for preparing Ai and Bi is `O(N)` as well.

Comment: thank you sir for this solution ^_^ it required some changes to suit my needs, but it's working :)